# Are some modifiers not supported by SendKeys.SendWait?

Tags: windows, vb.net, text, copy, sendkeys

I have a code that works perfectly, copying selected text from any windows application pressing CTRL+B.
However, when I change the modifiers that trigger the SendKeys.SendWait("^c") from MOD_CONTROL to MOD_ALT + MOD_SHIFT, the command SendKeys doesn't copy the text from the active window.
So pressing ALT+SHIFT+B still launch the command SendKeys, but the command doesn't copy the selected text to the clipboard.
Is there some incopatibility between the sendkeys command and the modifiers other then MOD_CONTROL?

I have tried registering different hotkeys, and different modifiers for each hotkey: sendkeys works with every hotkey with MOD_CONTROL modifier but doesn't with every hotkey with any other modifiers combination.

```
Public Class Form1  
 Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing  
    UnregisterHotKey(Nothing, HotKeyID)  
End Sub  

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load  
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, HotKeyID, MOD_CONTROL, VK_b)  
End Sub  

Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "User32" () As IntPtr  
Private Declare Function RegisterHotKey Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal ID As Integer, ByVal Modifiers As UInteger, ByVal VK As UInteger) As Boolean  
Private Declare Function UnregisterHotKey Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal ID As Integer) As Boolean  

Private HotKeyID As Integer = 1  
Private Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312  
Private Const MOD_ALT As UInteger = 1
Private Const MOD_CONTROL As UInteger = 2  
Private Const MOD_SHIFT As UInteger = 4    
Private Const VK_b As UInteger = &H42  

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)  
    If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then  
        Dim Modif As UInteger = (CType(m.LParam, Integer) And &HFFFF)  
        Dim Key As UInteger = CType(m.LParam, Integer) >> 16  
        If Key = VK_b And Modif = MOD_CONTROL Then  

            'Check foregroundwindow has a valid handle  
            If GetForegroundWindow <> IntPtr.Zero Then  
                'Send the Ctrl+C command to the active window  
                SendKeys.SendWait("^c")  
            End If  

        End If  
    Else  
        MyBase.WndProc(m)  
    End If  
End Sub  
End Class
```

If I change

```
        If Key = VK_b And Modif = MOD_CONTROL Then  

            'Check foregroundwindow has a valid handle  
            If GetForegroundWindow <> IntPtr.Zero Then  
                'Send the Ctrl+C command to the active window  
                SendKeys.SendWait("^c")  
            End If  
          End If
```

With:

```
        If Key = VK_b And Modif = MOD_ALT + MOD_SHIFT Then  

            'Check foregroundwindow has a valid handle  
            If GetForegroundWindow <> IntPtr.Zero Then  
                'Send the Ctrl+C command to the active window  
                SendKeys.SendWait("^c")  
            End If  
          End If
```

The command SendKeys.SendWait doesn'nt copy the selected text: can someone give me a clue?
Thank you

Comment: `SendKeys.SendWait("") SendKeys.SendWait("^c")`. If you have registered the HotKey with `MOD_ALT Or MOD_CONTROL`, that is. It's not shown here. You have shown just `MOD_CONTROL` as Key Modifier, in code. I also suggest to use .Net declarations instead of using VB6 style. `UInteger` is not `Integer`.

Comment: Well, I meant `MOD_ALT Or MOD_SHIFT`, of course. It's the same thing here, but you should have `Dim Modif As Integer = (CType(m.LParam, Integer) And &HFF)`.

Comment: You'll have much better results using `MOD_CONTROL Or MOD_SHIFT` as modifiers. Also, read the Remarks section of [SendKeys.SendWait()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait).

Comment: Thank you Jimi, of course when I tried different modifiers I did register the hotkeys with that modifiers. In effect the problem is not the key trapping: if I register a key with ALT+SHIFT+key, that combination will work and the flow of the program step into the command SendKeys.SenWait("^c"): is the SendKey that doesn't work. It seems to work only if I trap the hotkey with CTRL

Comment: It does work. I said that the combination `CTRL + SHIFT` works better because using `ALT + SHIFT`, after the first  execution, the foregroung window is not the ForegroundWindow anymore (even if it looks like it is). Try with Notepad. Send a `CTRL-C` with the Hotkey, then click on the Desktop, again in Notepad, then press again `ALT+SHIFT+B`. You'll see that it works again. There's this little catch. You'll have to store the handle of the ForegroundWindow and activate it again before activating the Hotkey again. Unless a new ForegroundWindow handle is the current.

Comment: Remember that the `ALT` key sends a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message, not  `WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP` messages.

Comment: @Jimi. Sorry but I can't get this code working. I follow your advice step by step, but still when I paste the clipboard into Notepad I don't have the selected text copied by the ALT+SHIFT+B

Answer (score 0):

At last I managed it to work adding the line:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300)
```

just before the command SendKeys.SendWait("^c")

It seems that SendKeys have issue with timing and the pause inserted resolve the issue.
So, now this code works:

```
Public Class Form1  
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    UnregisterHotKey(Nothing, HotKeyID)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, HotKeyID, MOD_ALT + MOD_SHIFT, VK_b)
End Sub

Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "User32" () As IntPtr
Private Declare Function RegisterHotKey Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal ID As Integer, ByVal Modifiers As UInteger, ByVal VK As UInteger) As Boolean
Private Declare Function UnregisterHotKey Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal ID As Integer) As Boolean

Private Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312
Private Const MOD_ALT As UInteger = 1
Private Const MOD_CONTROL As UInteger = 2
Private Const MOD_SHIFT As UInteger = 4
Private Const VK_b As UInteger = 66
Private HotKeyID As Integer = 1

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
        Dim Modif As UInteger = (CType(m.LParam, Integer) And &HFFFF)
        Dim Key As UInteger = CType(m.LParam, Integer) >> 16
        If Key = VK_b And Modif = MOD_ALT + MOD_SHIFT Then
            'Check foregroundwindow has a valid handle  
            If GetForegroundWindow <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                'Send the Ctrl+C command to the active window
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300)
                SendKeys.SendWait("^c")
            End If
        End If
    Else
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```